# The order of the group G where $x^{11}=e$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $(G,*)$ a finite group such that for any $x\in G$ $x^{11}=e$ where $e$ is the nuetral element of the group $G$. Than the order of the group $G$ can be:
>
> a) $1331$
>
> b) $131$
>
> c) $3113$
>
> d) $313$

I know that if $x^{11}=e$ than $11\mid {\rm ord}(G)$ ( the order of $G$) so the answers can be a) or c) but I do not know another criteria which can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Try some small examples. For example, can the order be 22?

Comment: If it were $3113=11\cdot 283$, Cauchy's theorem would say that $G$ contains an element of order $283$. But every element has order dividing $11$ so....

Comment: @MichaelMorrow The identity element doesn't have order $11.$ [What can be said is every element has order *dividing* $11.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lagrange's Theorem, since $x^{11}=e$ (and $11$ is prime), $\lvert x\rvert=11$ divides the order of the group. Note that $3113/11=283$ is prime, so, by Cauchy's Theorem, the group would have to have an element of order $283$

So you're nearly right.

Another useful tip here is a criterion for showing a number $n$ is divisible by $11$. We have $11\mid n=\overline{n_1\dots n_m}$ if and only if the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^m(-1)^{i}n_i$$ is divisible by $11$, where $n=\overline{n_1\dots n_m}$ is the decimal expansion of $n$.

Comment: So how can I continue to solve the problem. I do not know how to use the fact that it would be an element of order 283.@Shaun

Comment: Each nontrivial has order $11$ by hypothesis, @math8000.

Answer (score 1):

> If $G $ is finite and has exponent  $p $, $p$ prime,  then $|G|=p^m $ for some  $m $.

If not, then by Cauchy's theorem there is an element  $g $ of order $q\ne p$, for $q$ a prime.  And $g^p\ne e$, since that would imply  $q\mid p $.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If all non-neutral elements have order $11$, then the group has order $10m+1$.